# Excel VBA Says my subscript cannot be found

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I'm trying to copy from one workbook into another. I've coded in VBA a lot with Access databases; however, i've never done so with excel. My code keeps error'ing and saying my subscript is out of range. I looked this up and when compiling it basically can't find the worksheet withing the workbook i'm referencing when it absolutely exists and i have it named right. I've tried making sure each workbook is active before running each code, but it still has the error. Error is in line 1.

```
 Workstart = Workbooks(FileName).Worksheets("Mass&C.G_CATIA")

 WorkEnd = Workbooks("Copy of FEMAP_APS_Data_revB.xlsm").Worksheets("ReportGroupingInfo")

   FirstRow = Workstart.Cells(Workstart.Rows.Count, "D6").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

   LastRow = WorkEnd.Cells(WorkEnd.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
   
   Workstart.Range("D" & FirstRow).Copy_

   WorkEnd.Range("G" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, True, True
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `Set` for both lines one and two. Are you programmatically opening `Workbooks(FileName)`? `FileName` might actually be the issue.

Comment: You may need to supply the full path of ```FileName``` if you aren't already, depending on where it is located.

Comment: `Workstart.Range("D" & FirstRow).Copy_` - remove the `_` at the end.

Comment: When you assign a variable to an object (worksheet in your case), you should use Set mySheetVariable = [workbook.worksheet("sheetname")] like so.